# invoke RMI method from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, rmi

I'm writing a servlet that could make rmi call. I've write RMI server and tested it with a java swing client, and all goes fine. But i have a problem using it with servlet. 
When user open main web page, a servlet automatically call an rmi method for retrieve some information on a database, then build web page to show. 
When user click some link that fired another servlet that invoke another rmi method, i obtain an error:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.101; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at project.RemoteClass.getEngine(RemoteClass.java:33)
at project.MainServlet.processRequest(MainServlet.java:57)
at project.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:176)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
```

I think this can be caused by how i lookup registry and pass it to serlvets. 
For avoid to write everytime lookup RMI code inside each servlet, i thought to do a class (like a ConnectionManager used on JDBC clien) a class that lookup registry and give it back to invoking servlet:

```
public class RemoteClass {
    private RemoteClass(){}
    private static Registry registry = null;
    private static RemoteInterface interface_engine = null;
    private static final String rmiAddress = "192.168.1.101";
    private static final int rmiPort = 22222;
    private static final String skeleton = "ProjRMISkeleton";

    public static RemoteInterface getEngine() throws RemoteException {
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(rmiAddress, rmiPort);
        try {
            interface_engine = (RemoteInterface) registry.lookup(skeleton);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return interface_engine;
    }
}
```

and that error occours when this code execute registry.lookup method.
How can i solve it?

Comment: Is there really a server at 192.168.1.101 listening to port 22222? On the correct interface? Can you telnet over and see if it works?

Comment: sure, it works well. Also because if it doesn't work also the first rmi call should fail.

Comment: Do you really need to constantly reassign the `interface_engine` static field?

Comment: mmm no, it shouldn't be necessary static, but i don't want to create a  RemoteClass object each time that a servlet need to invoke remote method!

Comment: But you're still doing that. Note that every time a method executes `RemoteClass#getEngine` you always execute `interface_engine = (RemoteInterface) registry.lookup(skeleton);`, which is strange (and even strange because this method is not thread safe).

Comment: Correct. I've insert also a boolean static field for check if lookup method was already called and skip to return. it seems works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.101
>   ...
>   at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)

There is no Registry running at 192.168.1.101, in this case on port 22222 as you called `LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.1.101", 22222).`

Maybe your Registry exits after the first call. If you create it at the server with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` and don't store the result in a static field it is liable to be garbage-collected.